# Building DEB package for fsharp compiler

Tags: f#, deb

I would like to install the [fsharp compiler from Github](http://fsharp.github.com/fsharp/) on my Debian system, and the usual way would be to create a deb package first and then install it (so it is possible to uninstall it later, etc.). What is the easiest way to achieve this? All the examples of how to use `dh_make` assume you have a source tar.gz appropriately named, whereas I don't. Also I need to use some prefix for the autogen script:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

I am not sure it this makes the task any more difficult.

Comment: Send an email to the `fsharp-opensource` mailing list, that seems to be where most of the F#/linux activity is centered: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fsharp-opensource

Answer (score 1):

This should actually be fairly simple to achieve with a binary package - which will also be cross-platform because the F# compiler itself is written in F#. The compiler itself is fairly standalone and depends only on a few BCL libraries. There are versions that run on Mono.

More important than installing the compiler is the integration with your platform's build system(s). Microsoft ships a `Microsoft.FSharp.targets` file for MSBuild, I don't know whether that will work with Mono's [xBuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build).

I have put together a [blog post](http://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/f-3-0-on-appharbor/) that explains where to find the various bits that make up the F# compiler and how to package them to compile on a platform that has only .NET and MSBuild (AppHarbor in my case), which you may find helpful.